# WPF User form TextBoxes binding to a collection

Tags: wpf, model-binding

I have a client form populated with Textboxes (Firstname, Lastname, etc) which I am binding to a Property class PersonName that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  In addition, there is a 'Add Record' Button which when pressed will add the record populated by the user to an ObservableCollection

I am instantiating the PersonName Property object in the xaml normally like this:

```
    <local:PersonName x:Key="person"  />
```

and binding to the Textboxes like this:

```
    <Label Style="{StaticResource label}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="First Name" Name="firstNameLabel" Margin="0,0,15,0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource person}, Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"  />
```

My property is implemented as:

```
Public Class NameList
    Inherits ObservableCollection(Of PersonName)

    ' Methods 
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.Add(New PersonName("Willa", "Cather"))
        MyBase.Add(New PersonName("Isak", "Dinesen"))
        MyBase.Add(New PersonName("Victor", "Hugo"))
        MyBase.Add(New PersonName("Jules", "Verne"))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class PersonName
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    ' Methods 
    Public Sub New(ByVal first As String, ByVal last As String)
        Me._firstName = first
        Me._lastName = last
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    ' Properties 
    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return Me._firstName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._firstName = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return Me._lastName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._lastName = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName"))
        End Set
    End Property


    ' Fields 
    Private _firstName As String
    Private _lastName As String
End Class
```

I add the present record in  Add_Record_Button click event as :

```
    Private Sub addRecordButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles addRecordButton.Click

      Dim name As Jewellery.NameList = CType(Me.FindResource("nameList"), Jewellery.NameList)
      CType(Me.FindResource("nameList"), Jewellery.NameList).Add(CType(Me.FindResource("person"), Jewellery.PersonName))
```

This adds properly and the form is cleared.  However when the next record is added, the first record is still there but overwritten with the second record's details in the collection.  Any advice?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is that you are trying to achieve ? I can see that you are trying to use MVVM model .For a quick example you can refer to below blog for the same :
http://adityaswami89.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/simple-mvvm-with-wpf/

Alternative to the example in the blog, you can create a collection of Model class in the view model and update this collection on your button click using commands concept in XAML as :
http://adityaswami89.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/commands-in-wpf/

Kindly let me know if this helped !!!

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Your blogs are cool still having a look.  Basically, I would like to add records to ObservableCollection on clicking 'Add Record' button without using code behind and in xaml. Is it possible to initialize each time a new object in xaml and add to the collection?  When user is typing in the Textboxes form, these are bound to other controls on my form as well so I need a way to initialize a new PersonName object each time so that I bind the FirstName and LastName textboxes to the other controls dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: If you can please attach a screen of the sample with the expected functionality what you are trying to achieve  it would be easier to answer. 
Since from the above description a simple Notify should work !!! I am unable to get why you want to Add it to the collection ?

Comment: I cannot add an image.  Not enough reputation points :) Sorry for the ambiguity, but I am trying to bind the FirstName and LastName textboxes to a Datagrid below so that as the user types, the Datagrid's FirstName/LastName fields are notified and present record being filled can be seen typing in real time as well as the other records that have been previously added to the collection.

Comment: I initialized the PersonName property object like this <local:PersonName x:Key="person" />.  As you say a notify should work.  When I am binding this object to my Textboxes, adding to the collection works.  But when I click 'Add New Record' button to add a 2nd record, the 1st record's FirstName/Lastname are overwritten in the collection.  That's the problem.  Btw your blogs are really helpful and precise.  Thanks

Comment: https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/editable-combobox-in-mvvm/.  This blog gave me the answer by adding a new property NewMyObject and binding it to a dependency property of the target, say a Combobox Text property.  For example, Each time the focus is lost from the combo, I get a new object.